# В правильном ли месте substr_replace?

Tags: php

```
$img = file_put_contents('photo.jpg', file_get_contents(substr_replace($link['img'],'640x640.jpg',-11))));
```

Comment: разложите код построчно, и проверяйте значения в каждой строке.

Comment: @Эдуард почему вы думаете, что в коде ошибка,  что его проверять надо?

Comment: @teran не факт, что ошибка в коде - может быть так, что код возвращает не ожидаемый результат. Так вот чтобы проконтролировать каждый этап, нужно разложить код по строкам с сохранением промежуточных значений в переменные. Да и читать код станет проще.